# Spring Boot Jpa JPQL Selecting columns except specific columns

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

For example, I have two entities with a `OneToOne` association.

```
@Entity
class Entity1(
    @Column val columnToSelect1: String,
    @Column val columnToSelect2: String,
    @Column val columnToSelect3: String,
    @Column val columnToSelect4: String,
    @Column val columnToSelect5: String,
    @Column val columnToSelect6: String,
    @Column val columnToSelect7: String,
    @Column val columnToSelect8: String,
    @Column val columnToSelect9: String,
    @Column val columnToSelect10: String,


    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn
    val columnNotToSelect: Entity2
)
```

And, there are many times when I want to select except specific columns like `val columnNotToSelect: Entity2`.
That's because selecting `Entity2` will cause trigger another query that is NOT always required.

For now, I'm implementing that requirement like this.

```
interface Entity1Getter {
    fun getColumnToSelect1(): String
    fun getColumnToSelect2(): String
    fun getColumnToSelect3(): String
    ...
}

interface Entity1CrudRepository : CrudRepository<Entity1, UUID> {
    // select all columns
    fun findAll(): List<Entity1>

    // select all columns except columnNotToSelect
    @Query(
        "SELECT " +
        "e.columnToSelect1 as columnToSelect1" +
        "e.columnToSelect2 as columnToSelect2" +
        "e.columnToSelect3 as columnToSelect3" +
        "e.columnToSelect4 as columnToSelect4" +
        "e.columnToSelect5 as columnToSelect5" +
        "e.columnToSelect6 as columnToSelect6" +
        "e.columnToSelect7 as columnToSelect7" +
        "e.columnToSelect8 as columnToSelect8" +
        "e.columnToSelect9 as columnToSelect9" +
        "e.columnToSelect10 as columnToSelect10" +
        "FROM Entity1 e"
    )
    fun findAllExceptOneColumn(): List<Entity1Getter>
}
```

It's quite inefficient that I have to arrange all columns I want to query.

#### Question

1. Are there any different ways to **select except specific columns**?
2. Or, are there any different ways to **not to select associated columns**? (not to trigger another query)

Thx :D

Comment: Make the OneToOne association lazy. It executes an additional query because you left it eager.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The required behaviour in JPA world is called  `EntityGraph`. You can create a specific entity graph (or set of graphs if multiple are required). And then mark a specific query method to use this entity graph. As a return result you will fetch the original entity, but all other properties, which are not in graph will be in LAZY fetch mode.

For example:

```
@NamedEntityGraph(
    name = "Entity1.exceptColumn", 
    attributeNodes = {
        @NamedAttributeNode("columnToSelect1"), 
        @NamedAttributeNode("columnToSelect2"), 
        @NamedAttributeNode("columnToSelect3"), 
        @NamedAttributeNode("columnToSelect4"), 
        @NamedAttributeNode("columnToSelect5"), 
        @NamedAttributeNode("columnToSelect6"), 
        @NamedAttributeNode("columnToSelect7"), 
        @NamedAttributeNode("columnToSelect8"), 
        @NamedAttributeNode("columnToSelect9"), 
        @NamedAttributeNode("columnToSelect10")
    }
)
@Entity
class Entity1(
    @Column val columnToSelect1: String,
    @Column val columnToSelect2: String,
    @Column val columnToSelect3: String,
    @Column val columnToSelect4: String,
    @Column val columnToSelect5: String,
    @Column val columnToSelect6: String,
    @Column val columnToSelect7: String,
    @Column val columnToSelect8: String,
    @Column val columnToSelect9: String,
    @Column val columnToSelect10: String,

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn
    val columnNotToSelect: Entity2
)
```

And then in your data repository:

```
interface Entity1CrudRepository : CrudRepository<Entity1, UUID> {
    // select all columns
    fun findAll(): List<Entity1>

    // select all columns except columnNotToSelect
    @EntityGraph(value = "Entity1.exceptColumn")
    @Query("SELECT e FROM Entity1 e ")
    fun findAllExceptOneColumn(): List<Entity1>

}
```

Note: you are using the same `Entity1` class, but properties out of entity graph are marked in LAZY fetch mode.

Other way of achieving this is to use a projection query, in this case you are creating a DTO, and write a query for this:

```
data class Entity1Projection (
    val columnToSelect1: String,
    val columnToSelect2: String,
    val columnToSelect3: String,
    val columnToSelect4: String,
    val columnToSelect5: String,
    val columnToSelect6: String,
    val columnToSelect7: String,
    val columnToSelect8: String,
    val columnToSelect9: String,
    val columnToSelect10: String
)
```

And then in your repository you can define following:

```
interface Entity1CrudRepository : CrudRepository<Entity1, UUID> {
    // select all columns
    fun findAll(): List<Entity1>

    // select all columns except columnNotToSelect
    @Query("""
    SELECT new fully.qualified.package_name.Entity1Projection(
        e.columnToSelect1, 
        e.columnToSelect2, 
        e.columnToSelect3, 
        e.columnToSelect4, 
        e.columnToSelect5, 
        e.columnToSelect6, 
        e.columnToSelect7, 
        e.columnToSelect8, 
        e.columnToSelect9, 
        e.columnToSelect10
    ) 
    FROM Entity1 e """)
    fun findAllExceptOneColumn(): List<Entity1Projection>

}
```

Each of the approaches has its pros and cons, you decide which to use.

Answer (score 0):

@Ilya Dyoshin is right about quite a lot, but there are some pitfalls.
Firstly, `@OneToOne` is such a type of association that can't be easily fetched lazy in case of bidirectional mapping. This is because Hibernate has no other way of knowing whether to assign a null or a Proxy to this variable.
Breafly in ths case there are at least 3 options:

- use [Bytecode enhancement](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-enable-bytecode-enhancement-dirty-checking-in-hibernate/)
- use `@MapsId` along with `@oneToOne` annotation at the child side
- declare a `columnNotToSelect` association not as a `@OneToOne` but as a `@OneToMany List<Val>` and always return `columnNotToSelect.get(0)`.
  [Here is a fine detalization](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) of fist two cases .

Speaking of unidirectional association it's also not so easy as it might appear at first sight. As @Ilya Dyoshin wrote before, `EntityGraph` is a really nice thing, but you should keep in mind, that there are two hints which defines graph selection behaviour: *"javax.persistence.loadgraph"* and *"javax.persistence.fetchgraph"*. [In theory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.html) it must works as follow [EntityGraphType](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.html):

- FETCH: *When the javax.persistence.fetchgraph property is used to specify an entity graph, attributes that are specified by attribute nodes of the entity graph are treated as FetchType.EAGER and attributes that are not specified are treated as FetchType.LAZY*
- LOAD: *When the javax.persistence.loadgraph property is used to specify an entity graph, attributes that are specified by attribute nodes of the entity graph are treated as FetchType.EAGER and attributes that are not specified are treated according to their specified or default FetchType*

but in practice it almos always depends on a bunch of subtleties including JPA provider (Hibernate, EclipseLink etc) and its optimizer

### Lets see a small example

---

**DB**

```
create table debt(
    id bigint identity(1,1),    
    contract nvarchar(128), 
    constraint PK_DEBT primary key(id)
)

create table debt_detail(   
    r_debt_id int not null unique,
    dict_value_1 int,
    number_value_1 money,
    constraint PK_DEBT_DETAIL primary key(r_debt_id),
    constraint FK_DEBT_DETAIL_DEBT_ID foreign key (r_debt_id)references debt(id)
)

insert into debt(contract)
values(N'aaa',N'bbb',N'ccc')

insert into debt_detail(r_debt_id, dict_value_1, number_value_1)
select id, 1, 2.2
from debt 
where id in (1, 2, 3)
```

**Entity**

```
@Table(name = "debt")
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraphs({
    @NamedEntityGraph(name = "testDebt", attributeNodes = {
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "id"),
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "contract")
    })
})

public class Debt {

  @Id
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private Long id;
  @Column(name = "contract")
  private String contract;

  @OneToOne()
  @JoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "R_DEBT_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
  private DebtDetail debtDetail;

  ************
}

@Table(name = "debt_detail")
@Entity
public class DebtDetail {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "R_DEBT_ID")
  @Basic(optional = false)
  private Long refDebtId;
  @Column(name = "dict_value_1")
  private String dictValue1;
  @Column(name = "number_value_1")
  private String numberValue1;

  ******************
}
```

**Repo**

```
@Repository
public interface DebtRepository extends CrudRepository<Debt, Long> {

  @Override
  Debt findOne(Long id);

  @EntityGraph(value = "testDebt", type = EntityGraphType.LOAD)
  Debt findById(Long id);

  @EntityGraph(value = "testDebt", type = EntityGraphType.FETCH)
  Debt findDebtById(Long id);
}
```

**Manager**

```
@Component
public class DebtManager {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DebtManager.class);

  @Autowired
  private DebtRepository debtRepository;

  public void debt() {    
    logger.info("findOne start");
    Debt debt = debtRepository.findOne(1L);
    logger.info("findOne stop. {}", debt.getDebtDetail().getClass());
    //logger.info("findOne stop. {}", debt.getDebtDetail());

    logger.info("load start");
    Debt debtLoad = debtRepository.findById(2L);
    logger.info("load stop. {}", debtLoad.getDebtDetail().getClass());
    //logger.info("load stop. {}", debtLoad.getDebtDetail());

    logger.info("fetch start");
    Debt debtFetch = debtRepository.findDebtById(3L);
    logger.info("fetch stop. {}", debtFetch.getDebtDetail().getClass());
    //logger.info("fetch stop. {}", debtFetch.getDebtDetail());
  }
}
```

now lets call `debtManager.debt()` and take a look at the log:
`debtRepository.findOne(1L)` will produce something like this:

```
select
        debt0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        debt0_.contract as contract2_0_0_,
        debtdetail1_.r_debt_id as r_debt_i1_4_1_,
        debtdetail1_.dict_value_1 as dict_val2_4_1_,
        debtdetail1_.number_value_1 as number_v3_4_1_ 
    from
        debt debt0_ 
    left outer join
        debt_detail debtdetail1_ 
            on debt0_.id=debtdetail1_.r_debt_id 
    where
        debt0_.id=?
```

> ...INFO  ... - findOne stop. class ....DebtDetail

and other queries this:

```
    select
        debt0_.id as id1_0_,
        debt0_.contract as contract2_0_ 
    from
        debt debt0_ 
    where
        debt0_.id=?

    select
        debtdetail0_.r_debt_id as r_debt_i1_4_0_,
        debtdetail0_.dict_value_1 as dict_val2_4_0_,
        debtdetail0_.number_value_1 as number_v3_4_0_ 
    from
        debt_detail debtdetail0_ 
    where
        debtdetail0_.r_debt_id=?
```

> ...INFO  ... - load stop. class ....DebtDetail
>
> ...INFO  ... - fetch stop. class ....DebtDetail

all the requests contain queries to a `debt_detail`. It happed because the default behaviour for a `@OneToOne` in JPA is `FetchType.EAGER` and mapping doesn't have mandatory flag (optional=false). Differendce between "graphed" and "nongraphed" queries is due to last one is not strongly defined and Hibernate fetches all joined to the `Debt` entities whereas "graphed" queries always fetches all the entities that are within the certan graph but in our case `@NamedEntityGraph` annotatation does not contain any entities.
One more important thing - in all cases fetched type is `DebtDetail` i.e. entity class as is

Now lets add some stuff to the `@OneToOne` definition in the `Debt` class:
`@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)`

logs have been changed - for all cases one and the same result:

```
select
    debt0_.id as id1_0_,
    debt0_.contract as contract2_0_ 
from
    debt debt0_ 
where
    debt0_.id=?
```

this is because we directly defined `LAZY` strategy. But it is not the only change. `DebtDetail` class logging must look like this:

> ...INFO  ... - load stop. class .... DebtDetail_$$_jvst2bb_0

it means that the joined entity has been proxied and the parent entity (Debt) has a reference to a proxy object that doesn't contain any data of the concrete entity except a primary key. And this is why treatment to the `getDebtDetail().getClass()` didn't cause a `DebtDetail` fetching - we've read a proxy class property, not the concrete entity class.

now lets add DebtDetail direct reading: it will be enough to uncomment code logging with `debt.getDebtDetail()`.
logs have been changed again - for all cases one and the same result:

```
select
        debt0_.id as id1_0_,
        debt0_.contract as contract2_0_ 
    from
        debt debt0_ 
    where
        debt0_.id=?

...INFO  ... - load stop. class ....DebtDetail_$$_jvstadd_0

    select
        debtdetail0_.r_debt_id as r_debt_i1_4_0_,
        debtdetail0_.dict_value_1 as dict_val2_4_0_,
        debtdetail0_.number_value_1 as number_v3_4_0_ 
    from
        debt_detail debtdetail0_ 
    where
        debtdetail0_.r_debt_id=?
```

As you can see now the chain is: read parent -> log child's class type (proxy) -> lazy read of the child where proxied object will be "unproxied"

And if we will change propagation strategy to the `EAGER`, then both of entities will be read during the parent entity reading.

Summarizing `EntityGraph`es usage, pay the time to investigate your JPA provider behaviour and its changes depending on annotations definition.

[Here is](http://www.radcortez.com/jpa-entity-graphs/) another one nice article about entity graphs

Speaking of `Projections`:

It's not necessary to create a new class - an interface will be enough:

```
public interface DebtProjection {
  Long getId();

  String getContract();
}

@Repository
public interface DebtRepository extends CrudRepository<Debt, Long> {

  DebtProjection getById(Long id);
}
```

It's obvious advantage is independence from any relations - it'll return only properties that were defined

Answer (score 0):

I will just add to the other answers that the reason why the Lazy initialization will not work here is because your referenced entity is containing the JoinColumn. If the joincolumn is inside the entity that is referencing Entity2 then the lazy association will work. The other collegue is correct to say that using Bytecode instrumentation may solve your lazy loading problem in the case Entity2 is containing the JoinColumn.He is also correct that hibernate has no way to understand if the associated collection is null or Proxy, but this is only correct if the entity referencing does not contain the join column. As long as the entity holds the joincolumn there is no problem.

Lets look from Database perspective.

**With this setup lazy loading will work from entity1 to entity2.**

```
table Entity1 (
   id: varchar,
   entity2_id:varchar
)

table Entity2 (
   id: varchar
)
```

**With this setup lazy loading will not work from entity1 to entity2.**

```
table Entity1 (
       id: varchar,

    )

    table Entity2 (
       id: varchar
       entity1_id:varchar
    )
```

Unless you use bytecode instrumentation or instead of using OneToOne relationship you use OneToMany bidirectional event though it is OneToOne and expose appropriate interface corresponding to OneToOne relationship intead of exposing the collection.